# How to read data from file into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, input

My goal: to put each piece of data from file into an array. Then pass that array into the main method so I can call whichever piece of data I need and append it if necessary.

Where I am now: I have created the file and it's contents and put them into an array. When I try to call and print the array from my main method,  I get [Ljava.lang.String;@6dd4ea6c
What is this? Why won't it let me print out my array to the console?

Help?

My code:

```
   /**
Add in javadoc comments
*/


//import statements
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Try { 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        fileSetUp();
        System.out.println(fileSetUp());
    }

    public static void createFile(){
        //create file holding inventory information
        try{
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("inventory.txt");
            outputFile.println("3000.0");
            outputFile.println("Lamps 15.3 400");
            outputFile.println("Chairs 19.95 250");
            outputFile.print("Desks 95.0 300");
            int i =0;
            outputFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("File cannot be created."); //?????
        }
    }
    public static String[] fileSetUp(){
        //load the file information
        String[] data = new String[10];
        try{
            File file = new File("inventory.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                data[i] = (inFile.next());
            }
            inFile.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: array doesn't have a method named "add" and put "data" declaration outside the try block, if you want to add elements to array, assign values using data[i]=inFile.next().

Comment: Use java.nio.file and `Files.readAllLines()`, you'll have a much easier job

Comment: This "java.lang.String;@6dd4ea6c" indicates your memory location. Use toString() method to get the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is line oriented, take "the easy way out":

```
public static String[] getDataFromFile(final String filename)
    throws IOException
{
    final Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
```

Or just use the `List` instead of an array.

---

As to:

> When I try to call and print the array from my main method, I get [Ljava.lang.String;@6dd4ea6c

This is the string representation of an array.

Use `Arrays.toString()` of your array if you want the elements. Or, again, just use a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are objects, but they do not override the `toString()` method. Thus, when you try to print them, you get the default implementation of the `toString()`, which is essentially the concatination of the object's type and its `hashCode()`. To properly print it, you could use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] arr = fileSetUp();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```